# How to refresh the view if its properties are set on a different thread in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

Folks,

I create a thread and within that thread I invoke a method of an object (called myGenerator) to produce some integer values for me.

Each time a new value comes from a delegate method of myGenerator, I change the width value of a UIButton in the main view controller.

The value of button's width keeps changing as planned, but the button's width does not change visually.

I used `setNeedsDisplay` method after each change, but nothing happens.
Any idea how button's width can visually be refreshed as the second thread changes it?

*(please note that I need to get the new value in a separate thread).*

Thanks.

```
-(void) aMethod:{
//I use this method to create a new thread for 
//getting new integer values produced in myGenerator object.

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            [self.myGenerator ProduceAnewValueForButtonWidth];
        });
}


-(void) ValueIsReady{
//This is a delegate method which is fired 
//each time the myGenerator object generates a 
//new value for button's width via the thread above.

    [self.button setBounds:CGRectMake(180, 130, self.myGenerator.producedValue, 50 )];
    [self.button setNeedsDisplay];
    NSLog(@"value = %.4f, %.4f", self.myGenerator.producedValue, self.button.bounds.size.width);

}
```

Comment: you must update UI in mainthread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your UI in mainthread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread
    [self.myGenerator ProduceAnewValueForButtonWidth];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
        //Update your button width here

    });
});
```